# Is it legal for a school to keep property confiscated from students?

Tags: united-states, education, tennessee

If a school confiscates contraband that is not allowed on school property but is otherwise legal to possess, are they allowed to keep it, or is it required that they return it to either the parents or student?

If it matters, the state is Tennessee.

Answer (score 4):

#### By itself, it is not legal to keep it from you...

Property ownership doesn't work that way. Your neighbor doesn't get to keep your car, if your teenage kid parks it in their driveway and your kids teachers don't get to keep the iPhone the kid snuck into school. Nobody get to sell your house from under you, even if the kid uses the keys to scratch their name into school desks. Posession may change temporarily based on school rules, ownership does not.

#### ...unless you signed a contract agreeing to it.

The kid does not go to school in a vacuum. I'm sure the parents signed forms and documents galore. In those forms will be a description what kids can and cannot bring to school, what the consequences are and what happens to confiscated items. I have no idea if there is a generic template for this in Tenessee, that all private and public schools share, I doubt it. So you will have to look into what you actually signed. It might be legal, if you agreed to it beforehand.